# Question on having operators as values in ENUM in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have a configuration XML file. some nodes are used for computation purpose and I plan to tore the values like below

```
<OPERATION>&GT;=</OPERATION> <!-- GREATER THAN OR EQUAL --> <VALUE>1</VALUE>
<OPERATION>&LT;=</OPERATION> <!-- LESSER THAN OR EQUAL --> <VALUE>1</VALUE>
```

I use this XML in my C# class. I was wondering if i can have an ENUM for these operators? 
Is this possible?

Cheers,
Karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using XML serialization, you can try to use the `XmlEnum` attribute:

```
public enum Operation
{
    [XmlEnum(">")]
    GreaterThan,
    [XmlEnum("<")]
    LessThan,
    ...
}
```

<strike>I'm not sure how it will behave with these specific characters, though...</strike> *(I just tried, it works fine)*

---

EDIT

If you're using Linq to XML, you can just decode the character into an enum value by calling a method from within your query:

```
Operation DecodeOperation(string s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
        case ">":
            return Operation.GreaterThan;
        case "<":
            return Operation.LessThan;
        ...
        default:
            return Operation.Unknown; // or throw exception...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Expanding my requirement bit more, i have perform the operation based on the operation mentioned in XMl, i use LINQ to get the values in my method and use switch case for this. I am not serializing the XML

Comment: @Karthik K, see my updated answer. I don't think you can do better than a switch in that case. Alternatively, you can store the name of the enum value, and use `Enum.Parse` when you read it